# restart node.js forever process if response time too big

Tags: node.js, forever

I got forever script for managing `node.js` site.

Sometimes `node.js` site hangs and response time go above 30 seconds. And in fact site is down. Then fast cure for it is restarting `forever`:

```
$ forever restart 3
```

where `3` is script number in `forever list`.

Is it possible to make it automatically? Is there option in `forever` which make it restart if response time will be more than 2 seconds for example?

Or maybe I got to run external script which will check response time and make descension to restart hanging `forever` script.

Or maybe I need to write this logic inside my `node.js` site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you want to restart the server if most of the reply are taking longer than x seconds. There are many tools that helps you to restart your instances based on their health. Monit is one of them. In [this](http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit) guide, monit restart the instance if reply doesn't come back in 10 seconds.

If you want to kill the instance if one request if any of the requests are taking too long, then you note down the time when you take in the request, and note down the time when request leaves. If the time is too long, throw an exception that you know will not get caught and the server would restart by itself. If you use express, then check the code for their logger under development mode, as it tracks the response time.

Comment: Site not accessible for me, not sure if this is banned in my country of if the site is truly down now. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 2):

Aside [leorex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23713630/774086), I have something like this before to send 500 on timed out requests:

```
var writeHead = res.writeHead;
var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    res.statusCode = 500;
    res.end('Response timed out');
    // To avoid errors being thrown for writes after this, they should be ignored.
    res.writeHead = res.write = res.end = function () {};
}, 40000);
res.writeHead = function () {
    // This was called in time.
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    writeHead.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

You can use [addTimeout](https://www.npmjs.org/package/addTimeout) module to take away the timeout clearing part.

Once you implemented, you can handle as you like, you can just call `process.exit(1);` so forever will immediately replaces you.

You can make this smarter. Also in my application, if an uncaught error happens, I signal the supervisor process so that it will spin up another worker process and gracefully go down(close http server and wait for all pending requests to finish). You can do the same in your application, but make sure everything has a timeout callback as a failover/backup plan.

Comment: put an infinite loop before res.writeHead; the request will never timeout. so this doesn't prevent node from hanging up

Comment: Yeah, by itself, it's not good enough. I suggest doing this, and use Monit, to monitor it as leorex suggested in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23713630/774086)

Comment: I had a look to Monit, seems nice but is not updated anymore ? For timing out, wouldn't https://github.com/expressjs/timeout be a better option ? Assuming Express is used

Comment: BTW your approach of spinning up another process and gracefully closing the current in case of error is interesting. Do you have any code example of how you implemented that ?